# Why does animateLayoutChanges move the position of sibling views before animation ends?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have following XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/textLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/testList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/anotherLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/messageText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So when the `textLayout` is clicked, it will determine the visibility of `testList`.

When the visibility becomes `VISIBLE`, it works well. However, when the visibility becomes `GONE`, the `anotherLayout` goes back to original position before the animation of `viewGroup` ends, so it overlaps the `testList`.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Setting a view visibility to `GONE` means it no longer takes up space in measurements which means `anotherLayout` is doing the right thing by overlapping. What about trying `INVISIBLE` instead of `GONE`?

Comment: I need the GONE instead

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround to this?

Comment: The problem with INVISIBLE is that you'll have a huge gap on your layout.